# Python 34 filling width of scrollable frame in tkinter

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import textwrap

GUI = Tk()
note_frame = Frame(GUI)
note_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
note_scrollbar = Scrollbar(note_frame)
note_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
note_container = Canvas(note_frame, yscrollcommand = note_scrollbar.set)
note_container.pack()
note_scrollbar.config(command=note_container.yview)
def configure_note_container(event):
    note_container.config(scrollregion=note_container.bbox("all"), 
                width=200, height=200)
note_list = Frame(note_container, width=200, height=200)
note_container.create_window((0,0), window=note_list, anchor='nw')
note_list.bind("<Configure>", configure_note_container)
for x in range(100):
    exec(textwrap.dedent(
                """
                label_{0} = Label(note_list, text='{0}', bg="white")
                label_{0}.grid(column=0, row={0})
                """.format(x)))

GUI.mainloop()
```

I am trying to get the labels to stretch out to fill the X width of the grid cell within the frame (which is within a canvas so that I can use a scrollbar), but I don't know how to do it - when the `note_container` gets configured, it seems to cancel out any adjustment of size. grid_propagate doesn't seem to work either.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: My suggestion: start with just the note_frame, with nothing in it. Give it a distinctive color. Make sure it grows and shrinks as you expect. Next, add the note_frame. Give it a distinctive color, and make sure _it_ grows and shrinks as you expect. Then add the canvas. And so on. You've got too many problems you are trying to juggle at once. Also, don't use exec. There's simply no reason to create dynamic variables like that. All it does is make your code harder to manage.